# Почему код работает неправильно?

Tags: python-3.x

Найдите индексы первого вхождения максимального элемента в двумерном массиве.

Входные данные

Программа получает на вход размеры массива n≤10 и m≤10, затем n строк по m целых чисел, не превосходящих по модулю 2^31.

Выходные данные

Выведите два числа: номер строки и номер столбца, в которых стоит наибольший элемент в двумерном массиве. Если таких элементов несколько, то выводится тот, у которого меньше номер строки, а если номера строк равны, то тот, у которого меньше номер столбца.

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
a=[]
s=0
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
for row in a:
    for elem in row:
        s=max(s,elem)
    if s in row:
        b=a.index(row)
        c=row.index(elem)
print(b,c)
```

В упор не вижу ошибку

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь есть какая-то ошибка?

Comment: Потому что выводит неверный ответ, например при входных данных
3 3
1 2 3
4 10 5
6 7 8
Выводит 1 2, хотя должен 1 1

Comment: В строке `c=row.index(elem)` вы получаете индекс не максимального, а текущего элемента в цикле

Comment: Всё, понял, благодарю

Comment: А ещё код не соответствует условию "выводится тот, у которого меньше номер строки". Если есть несколько строк с максимальным элементом, то у вас выведется тот номер строки, который больше. А ещё код не будет работать с отрицательными числами

Comment: Спасибо, про то что он выводит последний максимальный тоже понял уже, а с отрицательными и не нужно